# Duplicated file with different mtime from Python os.stat

Tags: python, stat

Just noticed that when copying a file (`ctrl + c`) and past it (`ctrl + v`) to somewhere, its modified time is changed by checking with Python `stat()`. The modified time should not be changed by `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v`.

```py
st1 = os.stat(src_file)
st2 = os.stat(dest_file)
if st1.st_mtime != st2.st_mtime:
    print("File changed")
else:
    print("No change")
```

The result is

```
File changed
```

I print both mtime and see

```
src: 1606263776.94353, dest: 1606263776.9435298
```

It seems that the modified time is actually the same but rounded. This causes my code to run into an error condition. Anyone knows why this happens?

OS: Mac

Python version: 3.8

Comment: Do you mean copy+paste the file's icon in Finder?

Comment: Yes. GUI operation